# ¿Por qué al visualizar el reporte de Jasper Report me dice que el documento no tiene páginas?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

Esta es la consulta que uso en el Jasper y al visualizar el reporte me dice que el documento no tiene páginas, ni siquiera me pide el parámetro.

`fechaInventario` es el parámetro.

```
select caja.id_caja, caja.marca, caja.vitola, caja.nombre,
caja.capa, caja.tipo_empaque, caja.invent_inicial, ped.enero, ped.febrero, ped.marzo, ped.abril, ped.mayo, ped.junio,ped.julio, ped.agosto, ped.septiembre, ped.octubre, ped.noviembre, ped.diciembre, observacion_orden,  ped.total_orden, en.total_entradas, sali.num_contenedor, sali.cant_contenedor, sali.fecha_contenedor, sal.total_salidas 
from registrocajas as caja 
join pedidosnuevos as ped on caja.id_caja = ped.id_caja
join entradas as en on caja.id_caja = en.id_caja
join salidas as sali on caja.id_caja = sali.id_caja
join salidastotales as sal on caja.id_caja = sal.id_caja
where caja.id_caja = caja.id_caja and sali.fecha_contenedor=$P{fechaInventario}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Tenés checkeada la propiedad _Is For Prompting_ del parámetro?

Comment: ¿Cuáĺ es el código fuente de tu JasperReport? ¿Esa consulta arroja datos si la pruebas en la BD, sustituyendo el parámetro por el dato real?

Comment: gracias por los cometarios logre solucionar el problema, al parecer era solamente un espacio ;(